# Sanitizing input to stick into a hidden input value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe I am confusing this a bit, but I have a piece of code that works like the following:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    var myValue = $('#myInput').val();
    listSize++;

    var listItem = "<li>" + myValue + "<input type='hidden' name='foo" +
        listSize + "' value='" + myValue + "' /></li>";
    $("ol.myList").append(listItem);
});
```

If the text input value contains for example, a `'`, then this code breaks in terms of correctly adding the hidden input value.

I was thinking that using `encodeURIComponent` would do the trick, but it does not.

What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: What if you add the list item first and then set the value using $(elem).val(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this with html strings, create an actual element and set it's *value property* using `val()`.

You can sanitize any possible html out of it by first inserting the string into a content element as text and retrieving it as text.

Note that the *value property* does not get rendered in the html the same as *value attribute* does so quotes are not an issue

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    // sanitize any html in the existing input
    var myValue = $('<div>', {text:$('#myInput').val())).text();
    listSize++;    
    // create new elements
    var $listItem = $("<li>",{text: myValue});
    // set value of input after creating the element
    var $input = $('<input>',{ type:'hidden', name:'foo'+listSize}).val(myValue);
    //append input to list item
    $listItem.append($input);
    // append in dom
    $("ol.myList").append($listItem);
});
```

Comment: I was going to add my own answer for the sake of keeping the initial code close to what already exists and simply adding the .append before setting the val, however this answer is a bit of a different way of approaching it and works, so will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    var myValue = $('#myInput').val();
    listSize++;


    var listItemHTML = "<li>" + myValue + "<input type='hidden' name='foo'></li>";
    $(listItemHTML).appendTo('ol.myList').find('input[type=hidden]').val(myValue);
});
```

The appendTo function returns a reference to the just appended element.
Calling the val() function on the element will render the inserting of a quote useless since it will be interpreted as an actual value.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't see that as being in the scope of the question.

Comment: I misread your question the first go. Indeed the fiddle I sent didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way would be to write a wrapper

```
function addslashes (str) {
     return (str + '')
    .replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0')
}

var test= "Mr. Jone's car";

console.log(addslashes(test));
//"Mr. Jone\'s car"
```